Chrome MV3 extension: Getting "Site has updated in the background" notification even though userFacing: false flag is set
We're using WebPush in our newly migrated extension to MV3. It's both for user-facing notifications and background updates. Some users have been complaining that they are seeing "Site has updated in the background" notifications even though our registration code is as follows:
chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  installWebPush();
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  installWebPush();
});

export async function installWebPush() {
  const pushData = await registration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: false,
    applicationServerKey: urlB64ToUint8Array(PUBLIC_KEY),
  });

  if (pushData) {
    await syncWebPushToken(JSON.stringify(pushData));
  }
}

export async function syncWebPushToken(pushData) {
  const { storedToken } = chrome.storage.local.get(["storedToken"]);
  if (storedToken == pushData) {
    return;
  }

  await fetch("https://example.com/web-push-tokens", {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify({ token: pushData }),
  });

  chrome.storage.local.set({ storedToken: pushData });
}

function urlB64ToUint8Array(base64String) {
  // From this page: https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/how-to/integrate/web-push
}

Some users report seeing it all the time. I have been able to reproduce the issue by doing the following:

Install our extension on one Chrome profile and make sure settings are synced
Restart Chrome, but don't open the profile with our extension, instead open another profile
Wait for a silent push to arrive - then the "Site has updated in the background" notification appears

If I open the profile with the extension installed, then the notifications stop.

I was able to fix this by calling the subscription method in the main script of the service worker. Basically:
try {
  registration.pushManager.subscribe({
    userVisibleOnly: false,
    applicationServerKey: urlB64ToUint8Array(PUBLIC_KEY),
  }).catch(() => {
    // This will fail
  });
} catch (e) {
  // Nothing to do here, this seems to update the registration in Chrome so it's marked `userVisibleOnly: false`
}

chrome.runtime.onStartup.addListener(() => {
  installWebPush();
});

chrome.runtime.onInstalled.addListener(() => {
  installWebPush();
});

I'm not sure if this is a bug or if there is something wrong with in what order we call all the registration code. But I created a reproduction repo here: https://github.com/feederco/mv3-user-facing-bug
